exercice 6.2.1 in Brezis book contradiction to the open mapping theorem?
By exercice 6.2.1 in Brezis book we have that:
$E,F$ banah and $T∈L(E,F)$; $E$ reflexiv $⇒T(B_E )$ is strongly close in $F$.
Is this not a contradiction to the open mapping theorem ?
As far as I understand the open mapping theorem says that: $E,F$ banah and $T∈L(E,F)$ subjective then the image of open sets remains open.

$B_E$ is not an open set.

@geetha290krm So exercise talks about the closed ball not the Open ball ?

In standard FA notation, $B_E$ is the closed unit ball of $E$.

surjective not subjective

And of course, "Banach" instead of "banah".
